# FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) отправка сообщения группе. Как?

Tags: android, firebase

Подскажите, как осуществить отправку сообщения или группе или у кого установлено приложение? При чтении мануалов, понял как делать конкретному пользователю. Через токен. Но как отправить на несколько устройств? Как вариант отправлять тем кто в группе. Пример есть прямо в доках:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
"to": "/topics/foo-bar",
"data": {
"message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
}
}
```

Тут понятно, что отправляется всем кто в группе "foo-bar". Но как создать эту группу?  При дальнейшем чтении понял что надо вызывать

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Topic");
```

Но это подписка. А как создать саму группу в Firebase Console на которую подписываться? 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Ничего создавать не надо. Топики автоматически сами создаются и отправляются на сервера гугла при подписке на них с клиента. После подписывания на топик всем девайсам его можно сразу слать сообщения.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то при вызове из кода

     FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Topic");

эти топики будут созданы автоматом и появятся в консоли? Так попробовал но ничего не добавилось. Но проскакивала инфа что топики создаются на сервере в течении суток и потом должны добавится. в консоль Это так?

Comment: @Kamenev_D, да, я тоже так понял)

Answer (score -1):

В общем напишу здесь вкратце и всё вместе что собрал за два дня поисков, думаю пригодиться другим:

Создаем новый проект в Андроид Студио. В меню Tool->Firebase. В появившемся окне выбираем Notificatons. Нажимаем появившиеся кнопки. По сути всё готово. Можно перейти в Firebase Console и оттуда отправить сообщение. Но т.к мне было необходимо делать рассылку не с консоли а с ПК, то добавляем в

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("mainTopic");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "subscribe topic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Так обозначим группу, которой потом и будем делать рассылку. Кстати, оказалось что указанный топик не появляется к консоли (Но встречал инфу что там появляется через сутки) но работает и до появления.

В NetBeans код такой (Нашёл где-то тут же).

```
 public class SendNotificationMain {

public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "AAAAkK.....9ivSm8";
public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
public final static String DEVICE_ID = "/topics/mainTopic";


public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String DeviceIdKey = DEVICE_ID;
    String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM;
    String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

     try {
        URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        System.out.println(DeviceIdKey);
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("to", DeviceIdKey.trim());

        JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
        info.put("title", "FCM Notificatoin Title"); // Notification title
        info.put("body", "Hello First Test notification"); // Notification body
        data.put("notification", info);

        System.out.println(data.toString());
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
         System.out.println("Resonse: " + response);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

}
```

В переменной

```
String AUTH_KEY_FCM
```

вставляем server_key. Его можно глянуть в Firebase Console->Настройки проекта(Слева вверху значок шестерёнки)->Cloud Messaging.

А в переменной

```
 String DEVICE_ID
```

можно указать отдельный токен конкретного устройства. Тогда сообщение будет отправлено только ему. (Но как их получить с сервера и где они там вообще так и не понял). Если кто-то знает - добавьте пожалуйста.

Если всё прошло нормально то после запуска увидим такое вот:

```
/topics/mainTopic
{"notification":{"title":"FCM Notificatoin Title","body":"Hello First Test notification"},"to":"\/topics\/mainTopic"}
Response Code : 200
Resonse: {"message_id":6077623228911864338}
```

Где последняя строка подтверждает что всё прошло нормально и сообщение ушло. Так же там может быть указано что произошла ошибка.
В общем формирование сообщения происходит через json. Там же можно указывать и другие параметры. Но не понял как сделать что бы сообщение было доставлено, если к примеру приложение было закрыто. При запуске оно не появляется. Но как я понял надо создавать отдельный сервис, а так же отправлять не

```
  data.put("notification", info);
```

а

```
 data.put("data", info);
```

и уже в службе разбирать. Так же при таком подходе есть возможность указывать свои картинки для сообщений, звуки и т.д. Если кто-то разобрался, то будьте добры добавьте пример. Я на данный момент не разобрался.